# Exposing JS events as Component Outputs in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Within a component based JS library (ng 1.5, ng2, react, whatever), I'm wrapping a JS library that exposes around 20 events. 
The component instantiates the JS lib, attaching it to that component.

I'm exposing those JS events on the component as individual Outputs.

I feel like each event being a single output is nice because it explicitly tells you what's available to attach to, but are there any issues/recommendations against doing this?

Perhaps there's a maximum amount of attributes you can attach to a DOM node. The alternative would be exposing a single Output with properties like: `eventName` and `data`.

JS:

```
angular.component('thing', {
  controller: controller,
  bindings: {
    one: '&',
    two: '&',
    three: '&',
    four: '&',
    five: '&',
    six: '&',
    seven: '&',
    eight: '&',
    nine: '&',
    ten: '&',
    eleven: '&',
    twelve: '&',
    thirteen: '&',
    fourteen: '&',
    fifteen: '&',
    sixteen: '&',
    seventeen: '&',
    eighteen: '&',
    nineteen: '&',
    twenty: '&',
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<thing
  one="doSomething($event)"
  two="doSomething($event)"
  three="doSomething($event)"
  four="doSomething($event)"
  five="doSomething($event)"
  six="doSomething($event)"
  seven="doSomething($event)"
  eight="doSomething($event)"
  nine="doSomething($event)"
  ten="doSomething($event)"
  eleven="doSomething($event)"
  twelve="doSomething($event)"
  thirteen="doSomething($event)"
  fourteen="doSomething($event)"
  fifteen="doSomething($event)"
  sixteen="doSomething($event)"
  seventeen="doSomething($event)"
  eighteen="doSomething($event)"
  nineteen="doSomething($event)"
  twenty="doSomething($event)"></thing>
```